# full outer join not working

Tags: mysql, join

I Want to do a `full outer join` on 2 tables but I get this error, what am I doing wrong?

```
mysql> select * from cajas full outer join almacenes on almacenes.codigo = cajas.almacen;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'outer join almacenes on almacenes.codigo = cajas.almacen' at line 1
>   mysql>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far as I know, you can't do a full outer join in MySQL, so just run it as the `UNION` of a `LEFT JOIN` and a `RIGHT JOIN` as

```
SELECT * FROM 
cajas LEFT JOIN almacenes ON almacenes.codigo = cajas.almacen
UNION
SELECT * FROM 
cajas RIGHT JOIN almacenes ON almacenes.codigo = cajas.almacen;
```

I think this would fix your problem.

**EDIT:** After a quick Googling, I realized that the above may not be perfect for all cases.  Instead you could do

```
SELECT * FROM 
cajas LEFT JOIN almacenes ON almacenes.codigo = cajas.almacen
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM 
cajas RIGHT JOIN almacenes ON almacenes.codigo = cajas.almacen
WHERE cajas.almacen IS NULL;
```

See [this blog post](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/) for reference.