# FULL OUTER JOIN With MySQL, MySQL don't support ist what is the solution for more than 2 Tables?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, join, mysql-5.6

```
   select * from

(select col1,col2,col3 from tableA 
where col1 like 'somthing1'
and col2 like 'somthing2' ) as t1

left join

(select col2,col2, col3 from tableB
where col2 like 'somthing1'
and col2 like 'somthing2') as t2

on t1.col3= t2.col3

left join

(select col2,col2, col3 from tableC
where col2 like 'somthing1'
and col2 like 'somthing2') as t3

on t2.col3= t3.col3

left join

(select col2,col2, col3 from tableC
where col2 like 'somthing1'
and col2 like 'somthing2') as t4

on t3.col3= t4.col3

UNION

(select col1,col2,col3 from tableA 
where col1 like 'somthing1'
and col2 like 'somthing2' ) as t1

right join

(select col2,col2, col3 from tableB
where col2 like 'somthing1'
and col2 like 'somthing2') as t2

on t1.col3= t2.col3

right join

(select col2,col2, col3 from tableC
where col2 like 'somthing1'
and col2 like 'somthing2') as t3

on t2.col3= t3.col3

right join

(select col2,col2, col3 from tableC
where col2 like 'somthing1'
and col2 like 'somthing2') as t4

on t3.col3= t4.col3
```

[image]

Comment: [Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4796872/2298301)

Comment: the Problem is i need that for more than 2 tables?

Comment: `(A LEFT JOIN B UNION B LEFT JOIN A) LEFT JOIN C UNION C LEFT JOIN (A LEFT JOIN B UNION B LEFT JOIN A)`. As you can see this soon gets out of hand, so you might want to use temporary tables for intermediate results. I have never needed a full outer join between more than 2 tables (thank god:-) and performance will suffer severely by doing so. Are you certain that you really need this?

Comment: Yes i need that for the Work, they like to have all results, matched and not matched rows, all rows from each table . :-)

Comment: @Tarek, edit the question and add the tables' definitions and the columns that the joins will be based on. An image of tennis balls does not a good question make.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [full outer join not working](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115542/full-outer-join-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

1. Build a `VIEW` that simulates a `FULL OUTER JOIN` of `A` and `B`.  (Use the template given by some of the links.)
2. Build a `VIEW` that simulates a `FULL OUTER JOIN` of that `VIEW` and `C`.  (Use the template given by some of the links.)
3. Etc.

Eventually, you will have a `FULL OUTER JOIN` of all the tables without the ugly mess of compounding the number of joins needed.

Comment: if i join the first view with Table c wich Id mus i use to Join to C  (on view.col3=TableC.col3), the col3 of TableA or the col3 of TableB or is that the same thing?

Comment: Write out the View and the Join.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm coming awfully late to this, but...
If this were me, given that everything appears to be joining on col3, I'd do something like:

```
select 
t1.*, ​t2.*, t3.*, t4.*
from
(
select col3 from t1
union select col3 from t2
union select col3 from t3
union select col3 from t4
) allcol3
left join t1 on t1.col3 = allcol3.col3
left join t2 on t2.col3 = allcol3.col3
left join t3 on t3.col3 = allcol3.col3
left join t4 on t4.col3 = allcol3.col3
```